# Prolog error: out of local stack

Tags: search, prolog

I'm currently trying to finish up this assignment, and I can't figure out where why my termination doesn't end. I have made (or close to) a breadth first search algorithm for a maze that tracks what moves have happened.

```
fewestRotationsSingle(Maze, Moves):-
    search([Maze], [[]], Moves).

search([], [], []).
search(Mazes, [PH|PT], R):-
    length(PH, M),
    (M > 5 ->
        search([], [], R) ;
        append([PH], PT, Paths),
        (possible(Mazes, Paths, Mazes1, Paths1),
        checkIfDone(Mazes1, Paths1, Solutions),
        length(Solutions, N),
        (N > 0 ->
            member(R, Solutions);
            search(Mazes1, Paths1, R)
        )
        )
    ).

possible([], [], [], []).
possible([MH|MT], [PH|PT], Ms, Ps):-
    helpers:oneMove(MH, 180, M1),
    helpers:oneMove(MH, c, M2),
    helpers:oneMove(MH, cc, M3),
    possible(MT, PT, MS, PS),
    append([M1, M2, M3], MS, Ms),
    append(PH, [180], P1),
    append(PH, [c], P2),
    append(PH, [cc], P3),
    append([P1, P2, P3], PS, Ps).

checkIfDone([], [], []).
checkIfDone([M|Ms], [P|Ps], R):-
    helpers:checkIfGoal(M, G),
    (G = 1 -> 
        checkIfDone(Ms, Ps, R) ;
        (checkIfDone(Ms, Ps, S),
        append([P], S, R))
    ).
```

When I test I use:

```
Y = [[x,x,x,x],[x,-,g,x],[x,1,-,x],[x,x,x,x]],
fewestRotationsSingle(Y, Moves).
```

which gives me:

```
Moves = [180, cc] ;
Moves = [c, c];
ERROR: Out of local stack
```

Where am I going wrong?

```
use_module(library(clpfd), []).

trans([], []).
trans([H|T], R):-
    nodebug,
    length(H, N),
    emptyLists(N, E),
    append([H], T, M),
    transRec(M, E, R).

emptyLists(0, []).
emptyLists(N, R):-
    L is N - 1,
    emptyLists(L, S),
    append(S, [[]], R).

transRec([], A, A).
transRec([Row|Rows], Cols, Result):-
    transposeRow(Row, Cols, S),
    transRec(Rows, S, Result).

transposeRow([], [], []).
transposeRow([RH|RT], [CH|CT], Result):-
    transposeRow(RT, CT, S),
    append(CH, [RH], R),
    append([R], S, Result).

oneMove(M, 180, R):-
    move180(M, M1),
    dropPlayers(M1, R).

oneMove(M, c, R):-
    movec(M, M1),
    dropPlayers(M1, R).

oneMove(M, cc, R):-
    movecc(M, M1),
    dropPlayers(M1, R).

movec(Maze, R):-
    trans(Maze, S),
    maplist(reverse, S, R).

movecc(Maze, R):-
    trans(Maze, S),
    reverse(S, R).

move180(Maze, R):-
    reverse(Maze, S),
    maplist(reverse, S, R).

dropPlayers(M, R):-
    trans(M, S1),
    dropRows(S1, S2),
    trans(S2, R).

dropRows([], []).
dropRows([H|T], R):-
    dropRow(H, Q),
    dropRows(T, S),
    append([Q], S, R).

dropRow([], []).
dropRow([H|T], R):-
    numlist(1,4,NL),
    (member(H, NL) ->
        (append([H], T, S), dropPlayer(S, R));
        (dropRow(T, S),
        append([H], S, R))
    ).

dropPlayer([], []).
dropPlayer([H1|[H2|T]], R):-
    (H2 = - ->
        (append([H1], T, S1),
        dropPlayer(S1, S2),
        append([H2], S2, R)) ;
        (H2 = x ->
            (dropRow(T, S1),
            append([[H1],[H2],S1], R)) ;
            (H2 = g ->
                (dropRow(T, S1),
                append([[-],[H1],S1], R)) ;
                (append([H2], T, S1),
                dropPlayer(S1, S2),
                append([H1], S2, S3),
                dropPlayer2(S3, R))
            )
        )
    ).

dropPlayer2([H1|[H2|T]], R):-
    (H2 = - ->
        (append([H1], T, S1),
        dropPlayer2(S1, S2),
        append([H2], S2, R)) ;
        (dropRow(T, S1),
        append([[H1], [H2], S1], R))
    ).

checkIfGoal([], 0).
checkIfGoal([H|T], R):-
    findall(X, (member(X, H), X = g), L),
    length(L,N),
    checkIfGoal(T, S),
    R is N + S.
```

Comment: Can you perhaps walk us through your code? I know this a lot of work, but at least tell us what program you aim to implement.

Comment: Furthermore you call a few predicates from `helpers:` we don't have access to (afaik).

Comment: Sure, that should be fine. Give me a min.

Comment: This is supposed to be a breadth first search algorithm. To start, fewestRotationsSingle is the entry point, which leads directly into search. The job of search is to find all solutions of a given path length, if there are any. If there are solutions, it returns them, if there are not, it searches the next state space using the possible predicate to find the next possible maze states. checkIfDone is the predicate that checks the list after we get all possibles, and returns any that have a solved maze. the helpers are essentially edge points and return new maze states.

Comment: So the helpers:oneMove predicate takes the move in and then outputs one of three different possible mazes, depending on the move given. A maze is essentially a rectangular box of x's, which represent walls, and -'s, which represent spaces. There are also between 1 and 4 players in the maze, which fall according to gravity after the rotation (180 degrees, clockwise, or counter clockwise). Lastly, there is a g spot which represents the goal.

Comment: It seems to have something to do with my transpose predicate (trans), which is now causing the same "out of local stack" error on another part of my project.

Comment: Though further debugging, it seems to have to do with the way emptyLists is instantiated. It will go endlessly if I query emptyLists(0,R). Currently trying to get past this.

Comment: Good job narrowing it down! Put a condition in `emptyLists/2`: `emptyLists(N, R) :- N > 1, L is N - 1, ...`. Otherwise, on backtracking, `N` can go negative.

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response. I did something similar to that at the time. Thanks for helping me debug it guys!